# Use "woman" or "person" for female version of "how to be a good man"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

A friend of mine is reading a English textbook in which a girl thanks her mother. In the letter, one of the things she said was "thank you for teaching me how to be a good man".

The English textbook isn't very good - it has lots of spelling mistakes, for example. But my friend wants to know what the textbook should have said instead.

Would you say "how to be a good woman"? Or "how to be a good person"? What would be more normal English?

The sentence was in the following paragraph:

> Mom, I know I have never written even a note to express my thanks to
>   you before. But today, on this special occasion, I just want to tell
>   you loudly [sic]: I love you mom! Thank you so much for not only
>   giving birth to my [sic], but also teaching me how to be a good man.
>   Thank you, mom, for all what [sic] you have done for me, for the whole
>   family.

Comment: "a good woman" has (perfectly normal) gender-specific connotations, whereas "a good person" is generalized to humanity.  Then sentence might have meant either (or both).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"How to be a good woman" seems fine, but for some reason it hurts my ear (though I'm not a native speaker). In addition to Novice's answer, I would like to just point out two more things:

- *man* can mean not only "a male human", but also "human" in general
- *a good person* is a great phrase that can be used for anyone.

Comment: Your first bullet is true (and I upvoted your answer for mentioning that important fact), but I have a hard time imagining any young woman thanking her mother by saying, "Thank you for teaching me how to be a good man," except in some exceptional circumstance, such as if the daughter had entered some male-dominated field, and had received some advice from her mother that proved particularly helpful as she worked through the ranks. Even then, though, the word _man_ there wouldn't mean "human in general." The "Fall of Man" may refer to "humankind," but such usage is typically in the aggregate.

Comment: To me (a native speaker), the term "good woman" itself carries somewhat sexist connotations.  I picture Mom teaching her how to cook, clean, keep her husband happy, etc.

Comment: @cHao, Yes, unfortunately for us all, we've been indoctrinated to accept 'political correctness' as the way of the future.  There **should** be nothing wrong with a woman expressing happiness or gratitude for being a 'good woman. :-)

Comment: I agree with both J.R. and cHao. I think *a good person* is the only one that doesn't sound strange here.

Comment: @cHao that would be my impression as well. "A good woman" - "good at being a woman" specifically, with the implication of referring to a set of traditionally "womanly" skills. Whether it reflects badly on us for reading it that way or the society for ascribing that sexist meaning to the phrase is, uh, left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski: It's a very common cultural stereotype. Personally, i'd say the conspicuously gendered language implies a difference between men and women, and absent any explanation, makes us find one even if we wouldn't normally recognize one. That means leaning on our culture and leveraging those stereotypes.

Answer (score 5):

“*How to be a good woman*” is perfectly fine, but a much more attractive sentence would be:

> *How to be a real lady.*

Or alternatively,

> *How to be a perfect woman.*

If you want to refer to a person, generally:

> *How to be a great person.*

Comment: The "best" choice really depends on context, which isn't clear in the example.  *Lady* is felt (at least in much of the US) to be dated, and sometimes demeaning.  *Perfect woman* is a bit strong; *good woman* would serve better in most cases.  If the meaning really has nothing specific to do with gender, then "good person" is most suitable; if I could choose how I am viewed by the rest of the world, "good person" is what I'd strive for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yep, "real lady" sounds like something from the '50s. Which could be the intent, in which case fine, but it's not something an English learner should say: it's loaded with connotation. _Good Person_ is definitely best in the context given.